# the use of Next() in a node.js controller

Tags: node.js, express, functional-programming

I am following the wonderful node-express-mongoose-demo app ([link](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/master/app/controllers/articles.js)

in the articles.js controller, the .load function has a next() statement and I am confused about it - I thought that next() was only used in routing, passing the flow to the next middleware. why is next() being used here inside a controller? and why are the other controller functions (e.g. .edit ,see code below) NOT using next()..?

```
 /**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Article = mongoose.model('Article')
  , utils = require('../../lib/utils')
  , extend = require('util')._extend

/**
 * Load
 */

exports.load = function(req, res, next, id){
  var User = mongoose.model('User')

  Article.load(id, function (err, article) {
    if (err) return next(err)
    if (!article) return next(new Error('not found'))
    req.article = article
    next()
  })
}

....

/**
 * Edit an article
 */

exports.edit = function (req, res) {
  res.render('articles/edit', {
    title: 'Edit ' + req.article.title,
    article: req.article
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.load` middleware is calling `next()` because it is a [parameter middleware](https://github.com/madhums/node-express-mongoose-demo/blob/9be7bc846fb7f853bc981b2c26152dd3736981d6/config/routes.js#L91). These special middlewares allow you to perform logic for specific route parameters. This can be handy if you have a route like `/users/:id` where you could set up a parameter middleware for `id` that loads that particular user's profile from the database and then continues on to the actual route handler (which now has the user's profile already available to it). Without this, you may find yourself repeating the same loading logic inside route handlers for different HTTP verbs for the same route path.

The normal route handlers (e.g. `edit`) don't use `next()` because they don't need to (unless you encounter a serious HTTP 500-like error and want to call `next(err)` for example). They typically are the ones that send the response back to the client.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of named parameter in routing.

e.g for route like

```
app.get('/articles/:id/edit', ArticleController.edit)
```

we have to tell the routing to resolve "id" by setting `app.param('id', ArticleController.load)`

This will go on and load the article using the load method then call the next() to pass the control to edit function. "Load" act as middleware which load the article and makes it available in edit method.

Please see [express routing](http://expressjs.com/3x/api.html#app.VERB) for more details.