# Where does next() go in Express js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm new to javascript, nodejs, and express, and confused of using `next()`.

I want my code to move on to the next router with `next()`, but it seems to move on to the next `then`.

My code:

```js
//validation
router.post('/requests', (req, res, next) => {
let {myData} = req.body
basicCheck(res, cluster, myData)
        .then(() => {
            if (myCheck()) {
                next()
                return  // Doesn't need to do rest of the code. Just move on to the next router.post
            }
            ...
            return Promise.all(somePromises)
        })
        .then(() => {
            ...
            return Promise.all(somePromises)
        })
        .then(() => {
            if (someCheck() {
                next()
            } else {
                res.status(400).send('message') // My code reaches here! even when myCheck() is true
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            ...
        })
})


// where next() needs to be
router.post('/requests', (req, res) => {
    ...
})
```

When `next()` is outside the `basicCheck`, `next()` goes to the next router.post.

I don't get the concept of where `next()` indicates.

How can I correct this code while doing `myCheck()` inside `basicCheck()`?

Comment: The answer below has explained the concepts of middleware properly, as for your code reaching the bottom even when it's true, that's an expected behavior, if you do `return` in a `.then` callback function, then it will jump to the next `then` statement, not end the function. Please refactor accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [the use of Next() in a node.js controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23854961/the-use-of-next-in-a-node-js-controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `next()` you move to the next middleware.

Exapmle:

You have a route like:

```
app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
   res.send("hello")
})
```

Instead of using an anonymous function you can declare an function and use it it like:

```
function firstMiddleware(req, res, next){
   res.send("hello")
}

app.get("/", firstMiddleware);
```

What you can do is you can have multiple middlewares in your route like:

```
function firstMiddleware(req, res, next){
   console.log("hy");
   next()
}

function secondMiddleware(req,res,next) {
   console.log("hello")
   res.send("hello");
}

app.get("/", firstMiddleware, secondMiddleware);
```

As you can see. In my first middleware i use `next()`. This tells express.js to move to the next middleware in this case `secondMiddleware`

The middlewares gets executed from the left to right and with `next()` you tell them to move to the next until you are on the end.

Usually the last middleware is your API endpoint and you should not use `next()` otherwise you would "jump out" of your route and you would receive an error if you have defined an global error handler

Also sidenote: A bonus would be to seperate your routes and logic by creating an file called `controller.js` for example.

> controller.js

```
function firstMiddleware(req, res, next){
   console.log("hy");
   next()
}

function secondMiddleware(req,res,next) {
   console.log("hello")
   res.send("hello");
}

module.exports = {
   firstMiddleware,
   secondMiddleware
}
```

Now you can import it:

```
const { firstMiddleware, secondMiddleware } = require("./controller.js");

app.get("/", firstMiddleware, secondMiddleware);
```

This makes your code easier to maintain as it grows

EDIT:

```
router.post("/requests", async (req, res, next) => {
  let { myData } = req.body;
  let checkresult = await awbasicCheck(res, cluster, myData);

  if (myCheck()) {
    return next();
  }

  let someResults = await Promise.all(somePromises);
  let someMoreResults = await Promise.all(somePromises);

  if (someCheck()) {
    return next();
  } else {
    res.status(400).send("message"); // My code reaches here! even when myCheck() is true
  }
});
```

You use `return` witch yes stops the function from execution BUT what you also do is an promise chaining.

I have written here an async / await approach

Comment: Thanks for your answer. From your answer, I can get that next() will move on to the next router in simple cases. But why does it move on to the next then instead of router when it's in `then`?

Comment: @yoon well you use `return` witch keeps the chain. give me just a min