# How works next() in express

Tags: node.js, express

I think that I know why we use next() in expressjs in theory: :)

> In fact, the routing methods can have more than one callback function as arguments. With multiple callback functions, it is important to provide next as an argument to the callback function and then call next() within the body of the function to hand off control to the next callback.

But in practice I can't get it.

```js
app.get('/project', (req, res, next) => {
  con.query("SELECT * FROM issues", (err, result) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.send(result);
  })
  next()
  console.log("NEVER HERE");
});
```

This is situation where this code do not work.

`Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

1. But if I put `next()` right bellow `res.send(result);` and remove this one above `console.log('NEVER HERE');` statement it works perfectly.
2. Also if I remove `next()` on both places it works well.
3. And what I noticed is if I use `console.log(result)` instead of `res.send(result)` it works no metter where `next()` callback is.

My main question is why one `next()` "makes troubles" to other one, when they are used together with `res.send()`.

I'm new to express and also with mysql, thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does next() go in Express js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65069404/where-does-next-go-in-express-js)

Comment: Hi Ilija, your explantion is very good and general, I read it. 
It helps also. I accepted Molda answer for my current question.

Comment: thank you. glad to hear that it helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **are not supposed to use both** `res.send` and `next`

The purpose of `next` is to pass control to another middleware but when you respond to the request using `res.send(...)` there's no reason to that.

Simple example when you would use `next`:

```
app.get('/admin', function authMiddleware(req, res, next){
    // user must be logged in and be an admin to access this route
    if (req.user && req.user.isAdmin)
        next(); // this will pass control to the handler function bellow
    else // respond with 401 error
        res.status(401).send('unauthorized');

}, function handler(req, res){
    // only get here when user is admin
    res.render('admin');
});
```

Your example should look like this, you don't need to care about `next` at all:

```
app.get('/project', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM issues", (err, result) => {
        // don't throw, just respond appropriately
        //if (err) throw err;
    
        if (err)
            res.status(500).send('error occured');
        else
            res.send(result);
    });
    // calling `next` here doesn't make any sense unless you pass an error
});
```

You could use the `next` function but you should have setup an error handler and you need to pass the error ([Docs](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)):

```
app.get('/project', (req, res, next) => {
    con.query("SELECT * FROM issues", (err, result) => {
        // don't throw, just respond appropriately
        //if (err) throw err;
    
        if (err)
            next('error occured');
        else
            res.send(result);
    });
});

// Error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.error(err)
    res.status(500).send('error occured')
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Molda, you explained it very good.
I found that my issues was because, `next()` give me possibility to continue working in next callback (which I didn't have), and also my `req.send()` terminates the request-response cycle.